# Can IntelliJ run a client javascript code in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, intellij-idea

IntelliJ supports out of the box client side javascript debugging, when the code runs on either Chrome or Firefox.

Unfortunately, the wish of Douglas Crockford as expressed at 49:34 in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY&feature=youtube_gdata_player is likely to remain unanswered and IE9 is here to stay.

So, can IntelliJ be configured to run the client JS code on IE9 and be able to debug it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, I can not see that this is possible.  There is no IE option in the configuration dialog inside Intellij IDEA, and I can not find any documentation from JetBrains stating that it is possible now, or in the future.  But things may change.